# JS анимация. Как откатить анимацию на пару кадров назад?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Надо для проекта сделать игру 'кликер'. Суть в том, что при нажатии на кнопку полоса, идущая к персонажу, должна отодвигаться и после какого-то кол-ва нажатий ускоряться. Основную часть сделал, но не понимаю как сделать так чтобы при изменении значения кликов менялась скорость.

```js
let wall = document.querySelector("#wall");
let xPos = -200;
let abc = 2;

function animate() {
  xPos += abc;

  wall.style.transform = `translate3d(${xPos}px, 0, 0)`;

  if (Math.abs(xPos) >= 340) {
    xPos = 1;
    alert('Game Over! Your Clicks: '+a);
    a = 0;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();


let a = 0;
function clicker() {
  a++;
  xPos = 1;
} //клики

if (a == 5) {
  abc += 2;}
else if (a = 10) {
  abc += 3}
else if (a = 15) {
  abc += 4}
else {
  abc = 3}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#man {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: 200px, 200px;
    margin-top: 290px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
#game {
    width: 720px;
    height: 480px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#wall {
    background-size: 150px 480px;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 480px;
    background-color: red;
}
#button {
    margin: 75px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    font-size: 200%;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    background-color: grey;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 9px white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'mv boli';
}
#button:hover {background-color: grey}
#button:active {
    background-color: grey;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='game.css'>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>THE LIFE OF CODER</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="wall"></div>
    <div id="man"></div>
  </div>
  <input id="button" type="button" value="move" onclick="clicker()">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Даже если получится костылями это решить на keyframes, в игрушке потенциально может понадобиться накручивать разные параметры. Чем дальше - тем труднее будет этим управлять. Легче изначально писать анимацию на JS, в интервале стабильно увеличивая значение left на какое-то число. Тогда при клике можно будет просто уменьшить это же число. (см. `requestAnimationFrame` вместо setInterval)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Я вроде как переделал. Осталось сделать так, чтобы он ускорялся при нажатиях.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых переименовал переменные `a` → `clicks`, `abc` → `speedPoints`. Легко запутаться в ничего не говорящих буквах.

И добавил вычисление условной скорости стены, в зависимости от кликов:

```
speedPoints = Math.min(10, 3 + Math.floor(clicks / 5));
```

`Math.floor(clicks / 5)` — floor округляет число до нижнего целого значения. Для 0-4 кликов это 0, для 5-9 → 1, 10-14 → 2. Через каждые 5 кликов будет ускоряться. Когда доберется выше 10, благодаря Math.min останется на отметке `10` на протяжении всей игры.

```js
let wall = document.querySelector("#wall");
let xPos = -200;
let speedPoints = 2;

function animate() {
  xPos += speedPoints;

  wall.style.transform = `translate3d(${xPos}px, 0, 0)`;

  if (Math.abs(xPos) >= 340) {
    xPos = 1;
    speedPoints = 2; // <-- не забываем вернуть начальную скорость.
    
    alert('Game Over! Your Clicks: ' + clicks);
    clicks = 0;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();


let clicks = 0;
function clicker() {
  clicks++;
  xPos = 1;
  
  speedPoints = Math.min(10, 3 + Math.floor(clicks / 5));
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#man {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: 200px, 200px;
    margin-top: 290px;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
#game {
    width: 720px;
    height: 480px;
    border: 5px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#wall {
    background-size: 150px 480px;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 480px;
    background-color: red;
}
#button {
    margin: 75px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    font-size: 200%;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    background-color: grey;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 9px white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'mv boli';
}
#button:hover {background-color: grey}
#button:active {
    background-color: grey;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='game.css'>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>THE LIFE OF CODER</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="wall"></div>
    <div id="man"></div>
  </div>
  <input id="button" type="button" value="move" onclick="clicker()">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

`if (a = 10)` — это, кстати, частая ошибка новичков. Оператор присваивания `=` "записывает" значение `10` в переменную `a` и возвращает результат присваивания. Получается то же, что и `a = 10; if (10) ...`, которое в логическом контексте всегда будет `true`.

Оператор сравнения: `==`

Comment: Спасибо! Выручил.